# Can you populate a derived class object using data acess methods that return base class objects?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I want to create an inherited object that implements some new methods. The base class is simply a data container and is populated using a data access class.

I am attempting to use a mandated framework so my options for changing these base classes are VERY limited.

Since the inherited object has all the same data fields and accessors as the base I would like to use the base Data Access class (and its methods) to populate a derived class object. The problem I have is that the DA layer returns a populated object of type Base.

Effectively I am trying to copy the fields. I know that I could create a constructor that accepts the base object and effectively copy field by field but that is a maintenance nightmare doe to the nature of the underlying tables.

Is there any way to make the cast 'stick' without re-coding the DA layer?

I believe the only way to do this is to create a derived Data Access class as well that will handle the derived Base class, but is there a better way to do this?

The pseudo code is below. The example may look trivial but the DA layer encapsulates a LOT of data checks and exception handling so is quite hard to modify in any meaningful way without breaking a lot of existing functionality.

I hope it makes sense, it may not since a LOT of code has been dropped.

Base class(es)

```
public class oBase 
{
    #region "Constants"
    public const String FIELD_META_ID = "META_ID";
    public const String FIELD_MASTER_REF = "MASTER_REF";
    #endregion

    //Private Properties
    private Int32 m_iMetaID = 0;
    private String m_sMasterReference = "";
    //End Private Properties

    //Public Properties
    public Int32 MetaID { get { return m_iMetaID; } set { m_iMetaID = value; } }
    public String MasterReference { get { return m_sMasterReference; } set { m_sMasterReference = value; } }
    //End Public Properties
}

public class oBaseList
{
    private Int32 iMemberCount = 0;
    private List<oBase> m_BaseList = new List<oBase>();

    public Int32 Count
    {
        get { return m_BaseList.Count; }
    }

    public List<oBase> Items
    {
        get { return m_BaseList; }
    }

    public Boolean AddItem(oBase)
    {
        iMemberCount += 1;
        m_BaseList.Add(oBase);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Extended class

```
class oBaseExtended : oBase
{
    public oBaseExtended(int iMetaID)
    {
        ConnectionManagerSQL oSqlConn = new ConnectionManagerSQL();
        daBase MyConnectedData = new daBase(ref oSqlConn);

        oBase MyCastData = new oBaseExtended();
        MyCastData = MyConnectedData.GetData(iMetaID);
        oBaseExtended MyRealData = (oBaseExtended)MyCastData;
        return MyRealData;
    }

}
```

Data Access

```
public class daBase
{

    private ConnectionManagerSQL oConn;

    public daBase(ref ConnectionManagerSQL sqlConn)
    {
        oConn = sqlConn;
    }

    #region "Gets"

    public oBase GetBase(Int32 iMetaID)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(" SELECT  ");
        sb.Append(" META_ID, ");
        sb.Append(" MASTER_REF, ");

        sb.Append(" from myTable ");
        sb.Append(" where META_ID = @META_ID");

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), oConn.DatabaseConnection);
        comm.Parameters.Add("META_ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = iMetaID;
        SqlDataReader drMyTableData = comm.ExecuteReader();

        return PopulateMyTableData(ref drMyTableData).Items[0];
    }
    #endregion

    #region "List population "

    private oBaseList PopulateMyTableData(ref SqlDataReader drMyTableData)
    {
        oBaseList ocdMyTableData = new oBaseList();
        oBase ocd;
        ocd = new oBase();

        ocd.MetaID = drMyTableData[oBase.FIELD_META_ID] is System.DBNull ? 0 : (Int32)drMyTableData[oBase.FIELD_META_ID];
        ocd.MasterReference = drMyTableData[oBase.FIELD_MASTER_REF] is System.DBNull ? "N/A" : (String)drMyTableData[oBase.FIELD_MASTER_REF];

        ocdMyTableData.AddItem(ocd);
        drMyTableData.Dispose();
        return ocdMyTableData;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Apologies if this is unclear and for any pseudo code errors - I am a bit of a C# newbie.

I have updated the code to better reflect the real underlying code.

The question could best be put as: can I use cast and copy to an inherited type in one go simply...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your sample code would be a lot easier to understand if it were properly formatted, and conformed with normal .NET conventions. It's also incomplete, and does stuff that seems to be irrelevant (e.g. SQL connection handling). It's *much* easier to help you if you post real code instead of pseudo-code.

Comment: Noted Jon. BUT it *was* formatted OK but I couldn't get my head around the data entry screen - the actual code ran to seven pages so it was easier to mock it up!

Comment: Well it's not formatted correctly here - look at the indentation. I wasn't asking you to post your actual code, but instead a short but complete piece of *real* code, properly formatted and following normal conventions, so we can easily see what's going on.

Comment: BTW can you give me a pointer as to the conventions I have trampled on - as I said I am a bit of a C# newbie - my coding background is entirely different but I am quite happy with OOP principles - so my struggles are with what is possible/allowed in C# and some of the actual syntax - I keep using '<>' instead of '!='

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx is a good starting place. Classes should begin with capital letters, and names such as "MI" are meaningless. (It's also unlikely that you should be using `ref` everywhere you do...)

Comment: Oops - crossed with you.

Comment: Don't think so... I just added a comment straight after yours.

Comment: Thank you. Updated the code but I think I know the answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to copy values of properties and fields of the same name from one object to another.
Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Methods of interest are `GetProperties`, and `GetFields`.
Then in `PropertyInfo` and `FieldInfo`, methods of interest are `GetValue` and `SetValue`.

You can write a method for copying properties/fields and reuse it for each base/derived pair. Or any other pair of objects, as long as properties and fields of same name are assignable (ie. can't assign string to int etc.).

EDIT:
This method copies values of properties:

```
static void CopyData(object source, object destination)
{
  Type srcType = source.GetType();
  List<PropertyInfo> destProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>(destination.GetType().GetProperties());
  foreach (PropertyInfo destProperty in destProperties)
  {
    if (destProperty.CanWrite)
    {
      PropertyInfo srcProperty = srcType.GetProperty(destProperty.Name);
      if (srcProperty != null && srcProperty.CanRead)
      {
        destProperty.SetValue(destination, srcProperty.GetValue(source));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need it, try to add field copying too, it's identical principle.

Comment: I was also aware of this but reflection is probably beyond my abilities at the moment.... have you seen my code! Thanks.

Comment: Here you go. I added an example for copying properties to the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could populate the members shared by the derived class/base class via a base class constructor, you could also populate any extended members in the derived class if necessary:

```
public class oBase
{
    private Int32 m_i = 0;
    private String m_s = "";
    public Int32 MI { get { return m_i; } set { m_i = value; } }
    public String MS { get { return m_s; } set { m_s = value; } }

    public oBase() { }

    public oBase(int i)
    {
        // populate base class members using instance of data access class
    }
}
```

Your derived class would then extend the base constructor to populate any extended properties (i dont think you have any?):

```
public class oBaseExtended : oBase
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }

    public oBaseExtended() { }

    public oBaseExtended(int i) : base(i)
    {
        // this will invoke base class contructor to populate base members

        // then populate extended members afterwards if applicable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware that I could do this but it ends up getting quite long winded. I have ended up using a composite class with base class members that I can access directly but that makes direct Data Binding difficult... <sigh>